# Converting a string iso format date field to actual iso format type to store in mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, iso

I know there are so many questions and answers based on conversion of datetime field in python. 
Here I am having a date field in the format like "2019-10-30T11:29:43+00:00", which is type string. I need to embed this value in to mongodb. Here the value is storing as a str in the database. I need this to be converted and store something like ISODate("2020-05-27T14:57:31.302Z").

So far I have tried is

```
        date_iso = datetime.datetime.strptime(line['date_field'][:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
        date = date_iso.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

This returns the date in str type.

**Note: This is python 2.7**

Comment: You would store the date as a datetime object from Python (`date_iso` in your code).

Comment: More clear might be helpful@D.SM